# Unit testing a method that attempts to work with Nullpointer

Tags: java, spring, nullpointerexception, mockito

I am testing a method that resembles the following:

```
car.driveCar("carName", problematicMethod().getBrand());
```

`problematicMethod()` is a singleton that deals with security context. Normally, `problematicMethod()` would not return a Nullpointer but in unit testing, it does. I cannot change the source code for the method, and it cannot be mocked with Mockito due to its design. `driveCar()` does not return anything.

I've tried the following to see if it would suppress the evaluation of the line altogether:

```
Mockito.doNothing().when(car).driveCar(Mockito.eq("carName"), Mockito.any());
```

But it still gives me a Nullpointer exception because it tries to evaluate the second argument.

Comment: Why `problematicMethod()` cannot be mocked? Why does it return `null` in unit testing? Perhaps you could mock something the method relies on so that it does not return null in unit tests.

Comment: it is a singleton that deals with security context.

Comment: "it is a singleton that deals with security context." is a very important detail and should be mentioned in the problem description. If you cannot mock it because a mock can't be injected, you might want to rethink your architecture. If it contains static methods, use PowerMockito in conjunction with Mockito.

Comment: post edited. I cannot change the architecture or introduce new libraries so I guess there won't be any easy way to go about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing Mockito can do to solve your problem:

```
   car.driveCar("carName", problematicMethod().getBrand());
// [1] [5]      [2]        [3]                 [4]
```

Java's [order of evaluation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html) guarantees that the call to `problematicMethod()` will occur before the call to `driveCar`, so Mocking `driveCar` will do nothing to prevent the call to `problematicMethod`. Though you know Mockito will cause the call to `driveCar` to do nothing, the Java runtime can't know that.

---

You might try refactoring out the call to `problematicMethod().getBrand()`, and then test against an override or a Mockito spy:

```
public class YourClass {
  public ReturnType yourMethod() {
    car.driveCar("carName", getBrand());
  }

  /** Gets brand via problematicMethod(). Package private for test overrides. */
  Brand getBrand() {
    return problematicMethod().getBrand();
  }
}
```

(Note that this technique could also apply to the entire `driveCar` method call, and you could extract it to an object of its own if you had enough implementations to warrant [the Strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).)

Comment: I had to find another way to go about testing, but I'll still accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You're describing "problematicMethod()" as a singleton.  Methods are not singletons.  Classes can be singletons.

I think that what you're saying is that this class implements multiple concerns that you cannot separate, and as a result you have to test some methods while mocking other methods.

Assuming that's true, you're going to have to use the "Spy" concept in Mockito.  Read the Mockito docs about Spy.  This will make your tests messier and a bit harder to understand, but you've already done that with your class. :)